# imagettftext(): Could not find/open font in /usr/share/pear/Image/Canvas/GD.php

Tags: centos, php

I’m using this tutorial

http://www.phpbuilder.com/columns/ian_gilfillan20060503.php3?page=2

But when I try and use a font I see the following in http error log and no font is displayed.
From /var/log/httpd/error_log

```
  [Thu Nov 12 19:13:37 2015] [error] [client 10.0.1.103] PHP Warning:  Division by zero in /usr/share/pear/Image/Canvas/GD.php on line 1446 [Thu Nov 12 19:13:37 2015] [error] [client 10.0.1.103] PHP Warning:  imagettfbbox(): Could not find/open font in /usr/share/pear/Image/Canvas/GD.php on line 1473 [Thu Nov 12 19:13:37 2015] [error] [client 10.0.1.103] PHP Warning:  imagettftext(): Could not find/open font in /usr/share/pear/Image/Canvas/GD.php on line 1552
```

I tried using a different font as I couldn’t get the one in the tutorial to work but still run into the same problem.

This is the font line in the php file.

```
[root@gx ~]# grep font /var/www/html/image2.php  $Font =&
$Graph->addNew('ttf_font', 'DroidSerif Regular');  [root@gx ~]#
```

and in the font map file I have the following

```
[root@gx Fonts]# grep Droid fontmap.txt  DroidSerif
Regular,DroidSerif-Regular.ttf [root@gx Fonts]#
```

Which is located here.

```
[root@gx Fonts]# pwd
/usr/share/pear/data/Image_Canvas/Image/Canvas/Fonts [root@gx Fonts]#
```

I’m using a CentOS release 6.7

The tutorial says

….A common error at this point would be something like:
Warning: imagettfbbox(): Could not find/open font in /usr/share/php/Image/Canvas/GD.php on line 1245
This occurs if you don't have the correct (or any) fonts in your Fonts directory, found at php/Image/Canvas/Fonts/. Make sure that you have the corresponding .ttf file located in your Fonts directory.

but as I see it I have the fonts in place… don’t I ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

Please try put the fonts into below path:

```
/usr/share/pear/Image/Canvas/Fonts
```